# Div inside of anchor, stop redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have next html:

```
<a href="https://google.com" >
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</a>
```

Currently when I click to div `#first` it takes me to https://google.com.I don't want it. I want to not have effect anchor on div `#first`, so when I click on div `#first` nothing is happen.

And I cannot handle anchor, let say that I can add javascript just for div `#first`.

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell that my div contain form with attached event submit:

```
<script>
 function submitForm(_this){
    //do Ajax call
    return false;
 }
</script>

<a href="https://google.com" >
    <div id="first"></div>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
           <input id="email" name="Email" type="text">
           <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" type="submit">
        <form>
    <div id="second"></div>
</a>

So if I add this:
<script>
   jQuery("#first").on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
</script>
```

Then my form doesn't work.

**EDIT**
So if add e.stopPropagation() on input submit click, like this

```
<script>
   jQuery("#submit").on("click", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
   jQuery("#first").on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
</script>
```

It will work fine, but `e.stopPropagation();` doesn't work on fine in Safari. In Safari when I click on input submit it still leads me to the anchor link.

Comment: Don't put `<div>` inside a link, use `<span>` instead

Comment: when why wrap it in an `<a>`? why not `<div first></div><div second><a>...</a></div>`?

Comment: @ThomasRuiz `div` is valid for html5 - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: I am not adding <a>. This div is outputted from my wordpress plugin in footer. And some sites is wrapping footer with <a> so I want to prevent it

Comment: @Pete indeed, didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

cancel the click with [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```js
$("#firs").on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com" >
    <div id="firs">X</div>
    <div id="second">Y</div>
</a>
```

Comment: This is working but I have another problem. My div #first contain form which have onsubmit event, and it doesn't work if I put this. Check my last edit

Comment: than change it to `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Then it doesn't work, and event doesn't work with FF

Comment: Can you check my last edit and is that what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Either dont't put the div in the anchor, or use the following:

```
document.getElementById('firs').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might help (your id says firs but sake of spelling I'll put first)

```
$("#first *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

Answer (score -1):

use the following

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: You may want to specify where you suggest he should use this method.